# Htaccess Remove part of URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this URL: http://www.website.nl/pagina/4/wie-ben-ik.html

"pagina" is a real php document.
"4" is the id of the webpage, with the id I get the results from the database.

Can I change this URL to http://www.website.nl/wie-ben-ik with htaccess?

Thank you!

Comment: What doesn't work on this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule ?

Comment: Have you tried writing anything in your .htaccess file, first?

Comment: Questions of that sort have [been covered a lot](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+mod_rewrite+id+to+page). It just takes a bit of google effort to find, because the question titles are often likewise indescriptive. Use the common file-not-exist catch all RewriteRule and use a wrapper script to do the pagename -> id mapping in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the id some way or the other if you want it to query from the database.

Either use a query string (name-value pair) or have it in the URI like your are doing above.

If you do not want `pagina` in your URI you can have your URI's like this:
`http://www.website.nl/wie-ben-ik/<the number you want to send>`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(wie-ben-ik)/(\d+)
RewriteRule ^ /pagina/%2/%1\.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#redirect http://www.website.nl/pagina/4/wie-ben-ik.html to http://www.website.nl/wie-ben-ik 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /pagina/4/(wie-ben-ik)\.html [NC]       
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

#process wie-ben-ik as http://www.website.nl/pagina/4/wie-ben-ik.html
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z]+)$  pagina/4/$1.html [L,NC]
```